# Meaning of the syntax `const char (&x)[]`

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What is the meaning of the syntax `const char (&x)[]` in C++, is it something like pass pointer by reference to a function call?

Is it the same like `const char x[]`, which defines x as `const char*`?
And if both are one and the same where should I use `const char (&x)[]` instead of `const char x[]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const char (&)[]` is a reference to a const char array. The expression you showed is declaring `x` as a one of those.

> Is it the same like `const char x[]`

it's a reference to one of those

> ... which defines `x` as `const char*`

Um, no, let's take a step back.

```
const char array[5]
```

declares `array` as a an array of 5 const chars. It *doesn't* declare a pointer. However, arrays easily decay to pointers in C++, so for example

```
void foo(const char *);
// ...
foo(array);
```

is legal. In fact, arrays decay to pointers so easily, it takes extra care to pass them somewhere without decay:

```
template <size_t N>
void bar(const char (&x)[N]);

bar(array);
```

will actually get a reference to the array, and as a bonus, allow `bar` to deduce the array size.

---

Note that the only useful difference between a pointer and an array is the number of elements - when I quoted you saying `const char x[]`, I assume there will really be a number between the square brackets. If you omit that, it doesn't have any benefit over a pointer, unless you initialize it:

```
const char x[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

will still allow that call to `bar` to deduce `N=5`, even though you never wrote a literal `5` in your code.

---

It can also be used when you want your function to accept a fixed-length array:

```
void fun(const char (&x)[50]);
```

It's also usable with multi-dimensional arrays (but prefer `std::vector` or `std::array` when possible).

Answer (score 2):

> What is the meaning of the syntax const char (&x)[] in C++

This syntax mean that you want to use a **reference to an array** of const char.

> Is it the same like const char x[], which defines x as const char*?

No, it isn't the same, the main difference with **const char*** is that the size of the array became part of the type, so you can't pass an array with a different number of elements.

The main use of reference to array is in template where the number of elements is than deduced